# Spanning trees of a Graph G

Tags: graph-theory

Give an example of a connected graph G that is not a tree such that

a.Every two spanning trees of G are isomorphic.

b.No two spanning trees of G are isomorphic.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I have tried with the graph of K4 and K6.

Comment: Well, these two don't work for both question a) and b). But start the exercise by asking the following question for each of the two parts: How many spanning trees do you want in your graph ? Do you have better chances to find a solution if the graph has a lot of spanning trees or if it has few ?

Answer (score 2):

For a), it is clear that any spanning tree of $C_3$ (cycle on $3$ vertices) is isomorphic to $P_3$ (path on $3$ vertices).

For b), the simplest construction would be a graph with exactly one cycle of length $3$ (so there are only $3$ choices of edges to remove to yield a spanning tree). Add vertices to the graph until the spanning trees formed by removing one of the edges of the cycle are not isomorphic (I found an example with $9$ vertices that works, but there are simpler ones).

Comment: It should be $P_3$, path on $3& vertices in the first paragraph. For the second part, it's possible to have an example with 6 vertices by doing the following: take $C_3$, attach one vertex to a vertex of the cycle, and a copy of $P_2$ on another vertex of the cycle. Then, by removing one edge of the cycle, you either get $P_6$, $P_5$ with a vertex attached to the second vertex of the path, or $P_5$ with a vertex attached to the third vertex of the path.

Comment: @H.Potter $P_3$ is a tree so it does not meet the assumptions for a).

Comment: I mean, removing one edge of $C_3$ gives you $P_3$, not $P_2$, you don't remove any vertex.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Corrected, thanks.